# How to interpret "marked-content" operators MP, PD, BMC, BDC and EMC

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

I am using PDFBox lib to render content of PDF. There are some limitations (Type1 fonts are not supported, CMYK images are not supported, operators MP, PD, BMC, BDC and EMC are not implemented).

How should I interpret the operators MP, PD, BMC, BDC and EMC?

Updated:

```
operator: BDC args: [COSName{EmbeddedDocument}, COSName{MC1}]
operator: BDC args: [COSName{Document}, COSName{MC2}]
operator: gs args: [COSName{GS9}]
operator: cs args: [COSName{Pattern}]
operator: scn args: [COSName{P1}]
operator: re args: [COSInt{66}, COSFloat{570.302}, COSFloat{432.5}, COSFloat{23.278}]
operator: f args: [] // fill path
operator: k args: [COSInt{0}, COSInt{0}, COSInt{0}, COSInt{1}] // black color
operator: m args: [COSFloat{92.458}, COSFloat{559.601}] // move 
operator: l args: [COSFloat{93.769}, COSFloat{559.601}]
operator: l args: [COSFloat{94.699}, COSFloat{562.331}]
    ....
    ....
operator: l args: [COSFloat{88.003}, COSFloat{582.385}]
operator: l args: [COSFloat{92.467}, COSFloat{576.433}]
operator: l args: [COSFloat{88.196}, COSFloat{571.038}]
operator: f* args: []
operator: gs args: [COSName{GS10}]
operator: w args: [COSFloat{0.216}]
operator: M args: [COSFloat{2.613}]
operator: m args: [COSFloat{88.196}, COSFloat{571.038}]
operator: l args: [COSFloat{92.659}, COSFloat{571.038}] // add line to path
operator: l args: [COSFloat{94.624}, COSFloat{574.24}]
operator: l args: [COSFloat{96.545}, COSFloat{571.038}]
operator: l args: [COSFloat{102.076}, COSFloat{571.038}]
operator: l args: [COSFloat{97.507}, COSFloat{577.119}]
operator: l args: [COSFloat{101.649}, COSFloat{582.385}]
operator: l args: [COSFloat{97.186}, COSFloat{582.385}]
operator: l args: [COSFloat{95.328}, COSFloat{579.462}]
operator: l args: [COSFloat{93.513}, COSFloat{582.385}]
operator: l args: [COSFloat{88.003}, COSFloat{582.385}]
operator: l args: [COSFloat{92.467}, COSFloat{576.433}]
operator: l args: [COSFloat{88.196}, COSFloat{571.038}]
operator: h args: []
operator: S args: [] // stroke
operator: EMC args: []
operator: EMC args: []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are metadata related operators, they have no effect on rendering except when they are used with optional content. You can interpret them if they parameters have any logical meaning to your application, otherwise you can ignore them.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at the [PDF spec](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/adobe_supplement_iso32000.pdf)? It defines their usage and also keys they can take (like /ActualText).

Comment: "Marked-content operators (PDF 1.2) may identify a portion of a PDF content stream as a marked-content element of interest to a particular conforming product" - did't help a lot. I attached example of usage.

Comment: They define the 'metadata' around components so you can include info about text and shapes inside the PDF. BMC/BDC shows start and EMC end. They can be nested. The additional values are the metadata (ie the data between BMC/EMC is EmbeddedDocument element